# Haskell Stack build error - ghc.exe: could not execute

Tags: haskell, gcc, build, ghc, haskell-stack

Getting following error when trying to `stack build` [snowdrift](https://github.com/snowdriftcoop/snowdrift) on Windows:

```
Linking .stack-work\dist\i386-windows\Cabal-1.18.1.5\build\SnowdriftEmailDaemon\SnowdriftEmailDaemon.exe ...
ghc.exe: could not execute: C:\Users\Razvan\AppData\Local\Programs\stack\i386-windows\ghc-7.8.4\lib/../mingw/bin/gcc.exe
Completed all 6 actions.

--  While building package Snowdrift-0.1.4 using:
      C:\\Users\\Razvan\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\stack\\i386-windows\\ghc-7.8.4\\bin\\runhaskell.exe -package=Cabal-1.18.1.5 -clear-package-db -global-package-db -package-db=C:\Users\Razvan\AppData\Roaming\stack\snapshots\i386-windows\lts-2.13\7.8.4\pkgdb\ C:\Users\Razvan\AppData\Local\Temp\stack124196\Setup.hs --builddir=.stack-work\dist\i386-windows\Cabal-1.18.1.5\ build
    Process exited with code: ExitFailure 1
```

My question is how to obtain more information on this error as it is quite vague. Looking under `.\.stack-work\logs` I can't find any snowdrift related log. It is almost like setting the stack verbosity level to debug does not affect ghc/gcc verbosity level or maybe extra error information is just not there.

More information on the issue [here](https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/issues/466).

Comment: Can I suggest you run this instead:
`C:\\Users\\Razvan\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\stack\\i386-windows\\ghc-7.8.4\\bin\\runhaskell.exe -clear-package-db -package-db=C:\Users\Razvan\AppData\Roaming\stack\snapshots\i386-windows\lts-2.13\7.8.4\pkgdb\ -global-package-db -package=Cabal-1.18.1.5
C:\Users\Razvan\AppData\Local\Temp\stack124196\Setup.hs --builddir=.stack-work\dist\i386-windows\Cabal-1.18.1.5\ build`

(I reordered the package settings for you)

Comment: @Arnon It outputs `ghc: can't find a package database at C:UsersRazvanAppDataRoamingstacksnapshotsi386-windowslts-2.137.8.4pkgdb -global-package-db` The lack of double backslash is probably the problem.